# why upgrade to 12.10 is not shown

Tags: upgrade, 12.10

When I execute `sudo update-manager -d` I see a button to upgrade to 12.10. 
But when I execute `sudo tsocks update-manager -d`, I don't see an option to upgrade to 12.10. 
I can't execute `sudo tsocks release-upgrade`. This commands says there is new ubuntu release.

  
Why could this happen? 
By the way, I am running ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo -s
tsocks update-manager -d
```

This still won't show the upgrade, but there's nothing funny going on with command line parameters. There must be a problem with using socks and update-manager.

See bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/897686

I suspect upgrading this way might have been intentionally disabled because it fails later on, in the middle of the upgrade, which is bad.

I suggest to download the 12.10 ISO and upgrade using it, ie an offline upgrade.